# Android Listview Search filter (no result)

Tags: java, android, filter

i want to build search filter in android but failed... Any solution? please help me.. here my code:

**BoxOfficeActivity.java**

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
if (adapterMovies==null) {
return;
}
BoxOfficeActivity.this.adapterMovies.getFilter().filter(cs);
Log.e(TAG, "OnTextChange: " + cs + " start: " + arg1 +
" before: " + arg2 + " count: " +arg3 + " adapter: " +
adapterMovies.getCount());
}


public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, 
int arg2, int arg3) {
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
}
});
```

Comment: where is BoxOfficeActivity.java. it is not visible

Comment: Still not, can you post the code instead of (trying to send) a link?

Comment: i was updated my code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete example at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Add to manifest:

```
<application ... >
    <!-- this is the searchable activity; it performs searches -->
    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    <!-- this activity enables the search dialog to initiate searches
         in the SearchableActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity" ... >
        <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

In Java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use TextWatcher?

Comment: That part wasn't available while answering... I'll look into that